# jQuery .html() selecting only specific contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the returned value from the getbalance action except it's showing the HTML of the entire site.  How can I have it only show the result of the POST request which in this case is 0?  Code is below.

```
<?php

    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');
    session_start();

    //Create user if there is no session for the user.

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        $random = rand(10000, 100000);
        $create = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO users(user_id, balance, time, deposit) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $create->execute(array($random, 0, time(), 0));
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $random;
    }

    //All actions posted by jQuery (Method & Controller).

    switch($_POST['action']) {
        case 'getbalance':
            $balance = $dbc->prepare('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
            $balance->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
            $balance_object = $balance->fetch();
            echo $balance_object['balance'];
        break;
    }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var update_user_balance = setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { action: 'getbalance' },
                    success: function(update_user_balance) {
                        $('#balance').html(update_user_balance);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='welcome'>
            <h2>Welcome to Testing</h2>
        </div>

        <div id='properties'>
            <p>Your balance is <span id='balance'></span></p>
            <p><a id='deposit'>Click here</a> to deposit.</p>
            <p><a id='withdraw'>Click here</a> to withdraw.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your `php code` in a `separate file` like **balance.php**

And in `ajax code` replace `index.php` to `balance.php` like

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'balance.php',
```

**Otherwise** use `die()` after `echo` like

```
switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'getbalance':
        $balance = $dbc->prepare('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id = ?');
        $balance->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id']));
        $balance_object = $balance->fetch();
        echo $balance_object['balance'];
        die();
    break;
}
```

**or** use `die($balance_object['balance']);` in place of

`echo $balance_object['balance'];die();`

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this without having to make separate files..?

Comment: Its better to make a `separate file` for `ajax` otherwise you can `use die` after `echoing your data` in the `same page` see my `updated answer`

Answer (score 0):

After this code add exit(); inside switch - case : getbalance

```
echo $balance_object['balance'];
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
dataType:"text"
```

as a parameter of your ajax call.
Without specifying the dataType, AJAX will not know that the call expects something to return. The dataType refers to the returned type. Integer 0 could be represented as text "0" instead.

If it does not work, you can try deleting "success" key from AJAX call parameter.
Then, instead, do this

```
$.ajax({...parameters...}).done(function(response){...to be done after ajax call...});
```

You may need to check the action also. You can call a getbalance.php instead and write the function that returns your 0 there.